# Different border width for button

Tags: android, android-button

how can I set different width for a button on android? Like top and bottom are 2dp but left and right are 4dp? Thank you.

Update:

My apology if my question is unclear. It is not margin or padding. But I would like to customise the width like border-top or border-left in css. Is it possible in android?

Comment: your question is not clear.. how can you set top and bottom as 2dp.. you cannot set width that way... it can be height and width..

Comment: do you mean padding or margin?

Comment: @ayubin n ntc,  my question is updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear.Are you looking something like following?

```
<Button 
android:text="Button"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" 
android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</Button>
```